# Deployment time of the SharePoint Hosted app for online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am making SharePoint Hosted app while deploying this app it takes much time to deploy it around 15 min to uninstall and 15 min to install it.

Is there any way that we can see the changes without deployment?

Comment: You can keep your js/css files in a CDN or reference from a publicly available location, if that's what is changing. Update in CDN, clear cache and that should be it.

Comment: If you are just changing in JS file then rather than Deploy from Solution Explorer, Just press `F5`. First time it will retract and install the app, but later it will upload just changes in js within seconds. Use `F5`. But if you are making changes in AppManifest.xml or webpart file then it will retract  and install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is SP Hosted app, you can use the `SPFastDeploy` deploy tool to quickly update your files. Its basically as Visual Studio extension which will allow you to update your artefacts instead of installing and uninstalling the SP hosted app everytime there is some change in code.

[SPFastDeploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy)

Once you install it, you will get an image as below. Once you click on it, your artefact will be deployed and updated:

[image]